# ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a **Linux VM (with CentOS 64 bit)** where I installed **Oracle Database 11g Express Edition**. The database is running, I can use sqlplus and I can create tables and stuff. However, when I run a certain SQL script which inserts a huge amount of random data (~2 million rows) I get this error:

```
ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation
```

I already tried to increase `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` with the command below. As far as I read this should solve the problem (but it doesn't) since it increases the memory.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET = 40M scope = both;
```

However, the problem is that I can not set `PGA_AGGREGATE_TARGET` higher than ~40M (which seems to be not sufficient). If I try to set it up to 100M or more I get another error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02097: parameter cannot be modified because specified value is invalid
ORA-47500: XE edition memory parameter invalid or not specified
```

**Any idea how I can solve this problem?** It is perfectly fine for me to re-install the whole database or whatever.

*PS.: I asked the same question on dba.stackexchange.com since I wasn't sure whether it is programming or database administration.*

Comment: What is the `memory_target` value in your init.ora?

Comment: It is `memory_target=1G`

Comment: I'm not sure, but [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2283896?start=0&tstart=0) can probably help

Comment: Share the logic of sqlquery may be the connect by is creating huge virtual rows

Answer (score 0):

You are using Oracle 11g Express edition and it has certain limitations like database size doesn't grow up more than 11g and memory SGA+PGA doesn't grow up more than 1 GB. It means, you are encountering with somewhere this limitation. If you are not be able to expand PGA that means, you need to decrease SGA size first and after that try again. I will get success.